# .net8 Raspberry Pi Image

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w-2

Is it too early to ask if there is an image of .net8 for Raspberry PI 2w

I'm running IOT Module in .net7, and now want to upgrade and use .net8.  I think however that isn't available yet -- looking for confirmation and timeline.

This is how I built dotnet 7

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8

I thought I would try
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8

No joy however... got this working awhile back and now I wish I had better notes!

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/

Comment: Give this as an answer so I can give you the credit!